# Python3 openpyxl appending to an excel file from a dynamic web table

Tags: python-3.x, excel, selenium, openpyxl

I am trying to automate some of my daily workload. I need to input daily sales figures into an excel spreadsheet organized by sales rep.

Here is a picture of the table I am scraping:
[Dynamic Web Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCast.png)
[image]

Here is a picture of what my current program is appending to excel:
[What code is currently doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWDfe.png)
[image]
The current for loop I am using is:

```
sales_people = ["Domenic", "DEBORA DA SILVA", "Giulio", "Mike", "RONNIE MUKHERJI", "Sergio Sturino"]
for row in range(1, row_length + 1):
    sales_person_daily = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr["+str(row)+"]/td[1]").text
    if sales_person_daily in sales_people:
        sales_amount = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr["+str(row)+"]/td[5]").text
        sheet.cell(row=row + 1, column=num + 1, value=sales_amount)
    else:
        sheet.cell(row=row + 1, column=num + 1, value=0)
```

The issue is because the table changes daily (not all sales reps sell daily), the data figures don't get allocated to the proper cells.

The code above is extracting all the data I need perfectly, the problem is organizing it in the proper cells.

I can't think of a way to do this without using several nested for loops. Is there an easier way? I apologize if this question isn't posted properly, this is my first question on this site.

If more info is needed, let me know and I will post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain what your expected output should be? I'm having a little trouble figuring that out.

Comment: I am trying to get my dynamic web table to match my excel sheet perfectly. Right now it is issueing the wrong values to a sales rep. As pictures provided above, "Giulio's" sales figures are being issued to "Debora"

Comment: So in a day where Mike and Guilio don't make sales, the web table will only contain the other members? And the rows for mike and Guilio won't exist?

Comment: Nope sorry, Column A is stationary. The names are fixed values. The excel sheet is for an entire month, so all sales reps are mentioned, and if they don't make sales in a specific day I want to the value to be 0

Comment: try making use of defaultdicts from the collections module to allocates how values are entered based on the sales

Comment: I would suggest using a dictionary where the key is the salespersons name, and the value is the respective row. I am still having trouble understanding what your web table will look like on a day where someone doesn't have a sale, as you have not shown that. Will it be blank, or will it show 0 on the WEB TABLE? Also, i see you are using beautifulsoup, are you going through each day? Or are you just loading todays day and appending that data to the excel doc

Comment: Ah, now I understand your question. If there is no sales on a current day the HTML table will show blank (no names/numbers/ect). I am using Selenium, not beautiful soup. I am looping through each day of the month, extracting the table data then moving onto the next day.

Comment: Thank you maestro, I will look into that now

Comment: Sri, the issue with having a dictionary with sales person / row is the row changes every day depending on who did/didn't make sales. Can dictionary values be edited / modified daily? Even so, not sure if this option would work?